# Problem using Where() for Azure Mobile Service

Tags: c#, sqlite, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have the following test that doesn't work:

```
public class DesktopDTO
{
    public DesktopDTO() {}
    public DesktopDTO(string title, Guid otherId) 
    {
         Id = Guid.NewGuid();
         Title = title;
         OtherId = otherId;
    }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Guid OtherId { get; set; }
}

//setup environment:
MobileServiceClient mobileService = new MobileServiceClient("http://myserver.azurewebsites.net/");
IMobileServiceSyncTable<DesktopDTO> table = mobileService.GetSyncTable<DesktopDTO>();
if (!mobileService.SyncContext.IsInitialized)
{
    var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore("localstore1.db");
    store.DefineTable<DesktopDTO>();
    await mobileService.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store);
}
DesktopDTO input = new DesktopDTO("test124", Guid.NewGuid()); //this is my entity

//invoke action:
await table.InsertAsync(input);

//check results:
List<DesktopDTO> all = await table.ToListAsync();  //this returns 1 item
DesktopDTO r1 = all.Where(x => x.Id == input.Id).FirstOrDefault();  //this returns the created item
var query12 = await table.Where(x => x.Title == "test124").ToCollectionAsync(); //this returns 1 item
DesktopDTO r = (await table.Where(x => x.Id == input.Id).ToCollectionAsync()).FirstOrDefault(); //this returns null!!
```

The problem is that the last local query, which uses a `Where()` clause filtered by Id (which is the PK of the `DesktopDTO` entity), doesn't return the wanted entity.

The entity has been correctly INSERTed in the DB (as the other queries show, even the one filtered by "Title"), so I don't understand why the `Where()` filter should not work only with the PK.

I also tried using the `LookupAsync()` method, but again I got no results.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried passing the id as a variable rather than directly in the expression?

Comment: Yes, same result :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, I discovered the problem.

Azure Mobile Service doesn't allow to have (natively) fields like GUIDs. But it accept Guids and silently transform them into Strings, using UPPER CASE.

Therefore, the solution is to turn all the Guids into UPPER CASE in the queries.

You can do either:

```
DesktopDTO r = (await table.Where(x => x.Id.ToString.ToUpper() == input.Id.ToString.ToUpper()).ToCollectionAsync()).FirstOrDefault();
```

or directly:

```
DesktopDTO r = await table.LookupAsync(id.ToString().ToUpper());
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to reproduce the issue on my side. But I got the ArgumentException: "The id must be of type string".

[image]

If I change the Id type from **Guid**  to **string**, I can't reproduce the issue that you mentioned. I works correctly on my side.

```
public class DesktopDTO
    {
        public DesktopDTO() { }
        public DesktopDTO(string title, Guid otherId)
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            Title = title;
            OtherId = otherId;
        }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public Guid OtherId { get; set; }

    }
```

**Test Result:**

[image]